# Using environment-dependent source specifications in DBT

Tags: sql, dbt

I have a bit of an odd problem where I need to union together multiple source databases in production, but only one in lower environments. I'm using DBT and would like to use the [`source`](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/using-sources) functionality so I can trace the origin of my data lineage, but I'm not quite sure how to handle this case. Here's the naive non-source approach:

```sql
    {% set clouds = [1, 2, 3] %} {# this clouds variable will come from the environment, instead of hard coded. In lower envs, it would just be [1] #}
    {% for cloudId in clouds %}

    select *
    from raw_{{ cloudId }}.users

        {% if not loop.last %}
    union all
    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
```

This isn't ideal, because I'm referencing my `raw_n` schema(s) directly. I'd love to have something like this:

```yaml
version: 2

sources:
{% for cloud in env('CLOUDS') %}
  - name: raw_{{ cloud }}
    schema: raw_{{ cloud }}
    database: raw
    tables:
      - name: users
        identifier: users
{% endfor %}
```

So I can actually use the `source()` function in the sql files.

I'm not sure how to make such a configuration possible based on environment. Can this just simply not be done in dbt?

Answer (score 2):

Since `source` is just a python/jinja function you can pass variables to it. So the following should work:

```
    {% if target.name == `prod` %} {# this clouds variable will come from the environment, instead of hard coded. In lower envs, it would just be [1] #}
        {% set clouds = [1, 2, 3] %} 
    {% else %}
        {% set clouds = [1] %} 
    {% endif %}

    {% for cloudId in clouds %}

    select *
    from {{ source(cloudId, 'users') }}

        {% if not loop.last %}
    union all
    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
```

as for the environment part you would have to use `env_var` function but those are always strings so you would write `env_var('my_list').split(',')` assuming its comma separated.

EDIT:

Per askers, comments revised solution to include info as to what environment is being used

EDIT #2:

I know we left this off on a rather unhelpful note but now I am having a different issue that suggests a solution that might be more helpful for you.

in `dbt_project.yaml` you can specify multiple paths to models/tests/seeds etc. you can also specify dynamic paths. So you could potentially modify your `models-path` to something like this: `model-path: ['models','models_{{ target.name }}']` with this you have multiple `source.yml` `models/source.yml` will include all sources that don't change between dev/test/prod`and then sources that do need to vary will be in`models_{{ target.name }}`.
The same goes for models that will use them.

I know this isn't dynamic sources file still but it preserves lineages, and you do it in yaml just like you wanted.

Comment: I will admit that this solution is not great, I would be more inclined to `UNION` all sources in the table and just add an indicator column so when someone queries this table they can filter by source.

Comment: I'm not asking about how to parameterize the `source` function, I'm asking how to set up the `sources` in the `yml` spec file in a per-environment way. I admit, the original title of the question was poor.

Comment: so I updated the query to include env in it. As for updating inside of `sources.yml` you can use jinja templates in it, but I don't know of w way to merge two or more source tables together.

Comment: if you insist that you don't do this in the query itself may you should write a wrapper around `source` macro itself. Something that would contain that `if else` logic I added to my query.

Comment: whichever option you choose you will be able to build docs/graph it just will look slightly different between prod and dev environments. I hope that helps.

Comment: Not to be snarky, but you're pretty much just writing my _question_ back at me. I'm looking for a way to do this in the YML, not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting context here, I believe your primary interest is in working with the dbt docs / lineage graph for a prod / dev case?

In that case, as you are highlighting, the manifest is generated from the `source.yml` files within your model directories. So - effectively what you are asking about is the way to "activate" different versions of a single `source.yml` file based on environment?

Fair warning: dbt core's intentions doesn't align with that use case. So let's explore some alternatives.

---

1. If you want to hack something that is dbt-cli / local only, Jeremy [lays out](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/3428#issuecomment-856208742) that you could approach this via `bash`/`stdout`:

> The bash-y way
>
> Leveraging the fact that dbt/Jinja can write anything
> its heart desires to stdout, pipe the stdout contents somewhere else.

```
$ dbt run-operation generate_source --args 'schema_name: jaffle_shop'
> models/staging/jaffle_shop/src_jaffle_shop.yml
```

At least one reason that he points out is that there would be security implications if the dbt jinja compiler was un-sandboxed from the `/target` destination so I wouldn't expect this to change from dbt-core in the future.

2. A non-dbt helper tool.

From later in the same comment:

> At some point, I'm so on board with the request—I'm just not sure if
> dbt Core can be the right tool for the job, or it's a better fit for a
> [helper tool written in python](https://github.com/mikekaminsky/dbt-helper).

3. Use git hooks to "switch" the active "source.yml" file in that directory?

This is just an idea that I haven't even looked into because it's somewhat far-fetched but basically use your environment variables to activate pre-run hooks that set `source-dev.yml` to gitignore in production and vice versa? The files would have to be defined statically so I'm not sure that helps anyway.

Comment: I think this is the closest thing to an answer here, but it's still far from ideal. Thanks for your thoughts anyway @sgoley.  IMO the best solution would be having dbt allow for full-blown jinja templating in all yml files, instead of just basic `{{ expression_evaluation }}` statements. That way you could make something like this for-loop driven, and truly depend on the environment.

Comment: Yeah trust me, I looked into similar possibilities and would love to be proven wrong if there is a better answer.

Comment: :( I'll open an issue on `dbt-core` for this, I think

Comment: Seems like there are some open issues for it already actually